# Using two firebase projects in a single react native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, mobx

I have 2 firebase projects, one with a web app and another with an android app. I wanted to use both of them in my react native app. I am using the project with an android app for user management services like sending and verifying otp and registering user on firestore of that project. And I am using the other firebase project with a web app for the main business logic of my app. how can I correctly configure my app to use both projects correctly.

I have tried to integrate the android app with the google-services.json file and the web app with the firebaseConfig object. The app successfully authenticates the user with a phone number (which is by using the project with the android app). but after that, it fails to fetch a snapshot from the other web app project. and diplays this error
" ERROR  [2023-09-21T06:47:59.238Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (9.6.11): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend."
I am using mobx for state management.

Comment: You can do it with the Single Firebase project and in that add web app and android app. so you can manage both apps easily from single only.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to access multiple Firebase projects in a single app, as shown in the documentation on [configuring multiple projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects).

That said, there will be no implicit connection between those projects, so each will have its own users, its own database, its own analytics. You'll typically want these apps to all share at least the same set of users, in which case it's best to make all apps be part of the same Firebase project. That's the idiomatic and easiest way to share users and resources between multiple apps.

Comment: mm analytics can't be used as a multiple project, just make sure or pls share the source link.. cheers